# How can I debug latency in a UDP multicast request/reply?

Tags: python, udp, esp8266, multicast, arduino-esp8266

I'm building a real-time wireless link between a PC base station and a dozen robots, each transmitting at 60Hz.

For testing I wrote a Python script that sends UDP multicast packets over my WiFi network. And then on another multicast group I have two ESP8266 sending replies. One sends at 60Hz to simulate the real set-up, and the other spams at 10 times that rate to simulate congestion from the other devices.

First I only looked at packet loss, which was kind of as expected. But then I started to look at round-trip time. I made my Python script write the current time, and made the "real" node echo them back. (spammer messages are ignored)

With the spammer node turned off I get 10ms round-trip, but with the spammer, **it starts at 100ms and slowly grows to over a second.**

How can I debug this issue?

I tried to use Wireshark, but since they are separate UDP streams with custom data in them, I could not figure out any sensible analysis.

I figured the packets probably get stuck in a queue somewhere, so some googling suggested you can look at the queue length with the following command. Sure, the queue is not empty, but if I turn the spammer node off, nothing much changes in the queue length, while round-trip drops back to 10ms.

```
netstat -c --udp -an
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp    40256      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*
```

I thought maybe my Python code is just too slow to handle 600 messages per second. Running on PyPy made absolutely no difference, so I'm a bit hesitant to write the whole thing in C. It has almost 2ms per packet to do almost nothing.

Base station code:

```
import socket
import struct
import sched, time
import threading

base_multicast = '239.255.0.34'
robot_multicast = '239.255.0.35'
port = 8080


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', port))

mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(robot_multicast), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

# schedule base station packets

send_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
send_sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 2)

rate = 1/60
#sock.settimeout(rate)

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def send(now):
    nxt = now+rate
    s.enterabs(nxt, 1, send, argument=(nxt,))

    tstr = struct.pack("d", time.time())
    send_sock.sendto(tstr, (base_multicast, port))
    print(".", end='')


s.enter(1, 1, send, argument=(time.time(),))

t = threading.Thread(target=s.run)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

start = time.time()
avg_dur = 0
avg_ping = 0
while True:
  try:
      data = sock.recv(10240)
  except socket.timeout:
      continue
  now = time.time()
  duration = now-start
  start = now
  avg_dur = 0.99*avg_dur + 0.01*duration

  try:
      (t,) = struct.unpack("d", data)
      ping = now-t
      avg_ping = 0.99*avg_ping + 0.01*ping
      print(len(data), 1/avg_dur, avg_ping)
  except struct.error: # spammer message
      pass
```

Robot node: (spammer is identical, except it sends `replyPacket` 10 times in a loop)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "mywifi";
const char* password = "password";

IPAddress base_multicast(239, 255, 0, 34);
IPAddress robot_multicast(239, 255, 0, 35);

WiFiUDP Udp;
unsigned int port = 8080;  // local port to listen on
char incomingPacket[255];  // buffer for incoming packets
char  replyPacket[] = "Hi there! Got the message :-))))";  // a reply string to send back

int rate = 1000/60;
unsigned long mytime;
unsigned long count;

float avg_diff = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" connected");

  //Udp.begin(localUdpPort);
  Udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), base_multicast, port);
  Serial.printf("Now listening at IP %s, UDP port %d\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str(), port);

  mytime = millis();
}

void loop()
{
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize)
  {
    // receive incoming UDP packets
    unsigned long diff = micros() - mytime;
    avg_diff = 0.9*avg_diff + 0.1*diff;
    mytime = micros();
    int rcv_rate = 1000000/avg_diff;
    Serial.println(rcv_rate);
    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
    delay(random(rate));
    //Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);
    Udp.beginPacketMulticast(robot_multicast, port, WiFi.localIP());
    Udp.write(incomingPacket, len);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is probably due to queue buildup caused by the congestion the spammer node creates. One way to reduce the rtt is to reduce queue length in the wifi drivers. This leads to more loss, which is a trade-off you have to make.